# Angular Delay custom directive's link function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, q

i have simple custom directive that checks and sets `href` on its element.
But i need to check the href with data loaded from server (async) to make sure that user has access to that link(Kind of ACL).

So how can i delay the link function of doing its job until this data has finished loading?

Comment: @user3227295 if you mean $timeout with a delay, that is a very bad practice, and if you mean $timeout with no delay, $tmeout doesn't know about http requests and their status, that only works for $scope vars and digest

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i cook something up for my self, appreciate any pointers for improving it,
I made a [gist](https://gist.github.com/Exlord/11cfe71253673752c19b)

```
angular.module('myModule')
    .factory('dataLoader', ['$http', function ($http) {
        var __list = null;
        var __request = null;
        return function (callbak) {
            if (__list)
                callbak(__list);
            else {
                if (!__request)
                    __request = $http({
                        method: 'GET',
                        url: '/myurl',
                        params: {}
                    });

                __request.success(function (d) {
                    if (d.data) {
                        __list = d.data;
                        callbak(__list);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }])
    .directive('myDirective', ['dataLoader', function (dataLoader) {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            compile: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                return function (scope, element, attrs) {
                    dataLoader(function (acl) {
                        console.log(acl.length);
                        var href = attrs.myDirective;
                        if (href) {
                            if (href[0] != '#')
                                href = '#' + href;

                            element.attr('href', href);
                        }
                    });
                };
            }
        };
    }]);
```